# How to unnest rows with lists of varying sizes into a longer data frame?

Tags: r, nested, tidyverse, nested-lists, unnest

I'm working with a data frame that has tracking information on multiple individuals in the following format:

| ID | X | Y | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'albert' | *list of size a* | *List of length a* | a |
| 'betina' | *list of size b* | *List of length b* | b |

I'm trying to expand the table so that there is a row for each X/Y position, while retaining ID and list size information.

I've looked into similar questions posted on here and tried `unnest(df, cols = c(X,Y))` and `unnest_longer()` from the tidyverse/dplyr package, but all `unnest()` does is just convert the lists into vectors and keep the same format into something that looks like:

| ID | X | Y | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'albert' | c(xx.x1, xx.xx2...) | c(yy.y1, yy.yy2...) | a |
| 'betina' | c(xx.x1, xx.xx2...) | c(yy.y1, yy.yy2...) | b |

and `unnest_longer(df, cols = c(X,Y))` weirdly adds more columns (ex. X1, X2, X3, etc... ).

Additionally, if I re-run `unnest()` on the vector-formatted dataframe, I get an error saying that the different sizes of vectors are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Since I imported my original data from a massive data structure generated in matlab, it turns out that there was an additional layer of nesting I hadn't accounted for in my code or in the sample data frame described in my original post.